# find the conditional function (continuous- discrete)

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1$ be a continuous random variable with pdf $f(x)=\frac{2}{x^3},~~~~x>1$. $0 $ otherwise. Additionally the random variable $X_2$ is defined as $X_2=I_{[1,2]}(x)$. ($I$ := Indicator function)

Find $E(X_1X_2)$

I tried this $E(X_1X_2)=E(E(X_1X_2|X_1))=E(X_1E(X_2|X_1))$

My question is how do I find the function $f_{X_2|X_1}(X_2|X_1)$ when $X_1$ is continuous amd $X_2$ discrete? or I have to use law of iterated expectations?

Thanks

Comment: The distribution of $X_1X_2$, and hence its expectation, is not hard to get at.

Comment: What is the relationship between $X_1$ and $X_2$?  What does $I_{[1,2]}(x)$ mean?  What does "$x$" mean in the expression $I_{[1,2]}(x)$?  Do you really mean to say that $X_2$ is 1 if $X_1 \in [1,2]$, and 0 else?  I have no idea what the problem means, yet, assuming the problem can be defined, I suspect the solution can be done via something like $E[X_1X_2]=\int_{1}^{\infty} E[X_1X_2|X_1=t]f_{X_1}(t)dt$.

Comment: yes, $1$ if $X_1 \in [1,2]$, $0$ w